# FPDF - Data not flowing across multiple pages as expected

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm using the FPDF PHP Library to generate a PDF and I'm using a foreach loop to loop through some data and generate various groups of cell with information and an image inside.

I'd like for my generated PDF to firstly loop through but with each loop I need the cells to appear underneath each other rather than be grouped together as they are now (screenshot below).

[image]

The second thing I need to ensure is that with each loop they flow down and when there's not enough room on the page for the next loop, it begins a new page.

My current code loop is below:

```
if ($linked_documents) {
    $pdf -> SetY(120);
    foreach ($linked_documents as $document) {
        $pdf -> SetTextColor(51,51,51);
        $pdf -> SetFont('Manrope SemiBold', '', 10);
        $pdf -> Cell(20,7,'ID',1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf -> Cell(0,7,'Comments',1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf -> Ln(7);
        $pdf -> SetFont('Manrope Light', '', 10);
        $pdf -> Cell(20,7,'1',1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf -> Cell(0,7,'Comments about this image',1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf -> Ln(7);
        $image_1 = "image.png";
        $image_1_top_margin = $pdf->GetY() + 5;
        $pdf -> Cell(0,45,$pdf->Image($image_1, 15, $image_1_top_margin, 0, 35),1,0,'L',0);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve these two thing? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Change your last line to `$pdf -> Cell(0,45,$pdf->Image($image_1, 15, $image_1_top_margin, 0, 35),1,1,'L',0)` or `$pdf -> Cell(0,45,$pdf->Image($image_1, 15, $image_1_top_margin, 0, 35),1,2,'L',0)`

Comment: @GiovannaPennaEirada Thanks you so much, this has worked. The cells are now flowing down. The only thing now is that I would like a new page to be auto-created but without breaking the cells. See this image [here](https://imgur.com/a/s8RXao0).

The cells are breaking over the footer.

Comment: This is more complex, you can use the function `AddPage()` after a couple register, like counting five register and put the function `AddPage()` for generate a new page. I suger you read the documentation of FDFP: http://www.fpdf.org/ for more information.

Comment: Don't embed calls to `Image()` inside `Cell()`. It makes no sense because `Image()` returns nothng.